# Kotlinx.serialization not working on androidTest

Tags: android, kotlin, serialization, android-testing, kotlinx.serialization

Have Ktor setup and working fine in my project.  When running androidTest ("instrumentation tests") I get a `NoSuchMethodError` for Json.nonstrict.parse()code running in the tests.  This is code in the test apk, not in the app.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method parse(Lkotlinx/serialization/DeserializationStrategy;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lkotlinx/serialization/json/Json; or its super classes (declaration of 'kotlinx.serialization.json.Json' appears in /data/app/com.myapp-xT3-gAo92lzVXQoXVSRCnw==/base.apk)
```

The Kotlinx.serialization dependencies are declared in the module and I have tried `implementation` and `androidImplementation`.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but on the Kotlin repo there is an issue that revolves around this same error. Currently it is still unresolved.

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/576